# Uses_permission ignored in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I've got this strange error when building my project in Android Studio. Basically my app uses GPS to get the current location of the user.So in my androidmanifest.xml i've placed this line:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But when building the app,this exception keeps popping up:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: Provider gps requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
```

When using the networkprovider for the lastKnownLocation, the app works fine (and will most likely use another permission).

EDIT: the permissions tag is not within the Application tag.

Does anyone recognize this error?

Comment: Where exactly did you include the uses-permission-tag? Do you possibly have multiple build flavors with different AndroidManifest files?

Comment: clean the project and retry.

Comment: is your uses-permission-tag inside application tag or outside if first move it outside

Comment: Please post your entire manifest.

Answer (score 4):

Place it outside application tag.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <application.....
```

Make sure the uses-permission element is not inside the application element. Android Studio will not show any problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've now rebuild the entire manifestfile and the error is gone. But essentially this is just a 1:1 copy of the old manifest file. So it's still a mystery what caused the error in the first place.

Thanks for all the help and advice!

Comment: Too bad you don't really know what was going wrong ...

I have a similar problem now where I need an additional permission for a test, and the AndroidManifest.xml I provide is not merged into the final manifest for the test APK.